# How to add tags to files in Windows 7 so that they appear in search results

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, tags

In Windows 7, I want to add tags to my files (PDF, Word, Images etc) so that they appear directly in the search results, regardless of their content, title etc.

[This link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/help/find-what-you-are-looking-for-staying-organized-in-windows-7) shows how to search by tag, but it does not tell how to add a tag in any file.

In the long term, I'm planning to add such tags programmatically as well.

Comment: [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file) should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it from windows explorer view
[image]
Just select a file that can have tags added to it and adjust those in the bottom pane. Doesn't matter which view you're using. The link I provided in my comment should help as well. You need to identify that the file type will allow tags as some will not or require third party tools - [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-do-i-add-tags-to-pdf-and-txt-files/203b60ca-b773-4931-85ad-a5e67656d6ce) provides a solution for .pdf files, for instance

Comment: It doesn't work with other files

Comment: [Add tags or other properties to a file](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/add-tags-or-other-properties-to-a-file) should also be useful.

Comment: I could add tags to some files only ... Can i do the same to folder?

Comment: Tip: **hit Enter**.  The tag is silently ignored if you click away from the Add-a-tag dialog.