# categorizing files like that of Wikipedia

Tags: microsoft-word, file-management

Is there any tool to put each of our files in a certain category like Wikipedia so we could call them with that category? there may be several category for one file (so we could not use a simple folder as a category) and subcategories just like Wikipedia.

Is there any file manager, desktop search engine, tagging system or anything else to do this? BTW, I need that only for Word documents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add tags to files in Windows 7 so that they appear in search results](http://superuser.com/questions/385546/how-to-add-tags-to-files-in-windows-7-so-that-they-appear-in-search-results)

Comment: A better place to ask  for software recommendations would be https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

You can add tags to Microsoft Word documents and many other file types in windows explorer.

1. Right-click the file, choose the details tab
2. At the top, you'll have Title, Subject, and Tags
3. Add the tags you want, separated by semicolons (that may vary depending on your regional settings)

Now, in windows explorer, search by `tag:X` to search for all documents tagged with X.

Comment: Also, if you want to see your tags in Windows Explorer, right-click the column headers and add the "tags" column.

Comment: but I cannot edit tags for some of file types like Word. Why? (I edited jpg file tags and searced tag:x and it's OK)

Comment: I'm not sure - I can edit tags for Word documents fine. You can try editing categories if tags don't work for you.

Comment: Actually, I see what the problem is - you can only edit tags and categories if you can edit the file. Read-only files or files you can't even read you can't categorize like this.

Comment: no, it's not read-only. Recently I found that we cannot edit tags on some files such as txt files. Maybe docx files be as such

Comment: You could also try downloading the [Microsoft Office Filter Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17062). This allows windows search to search to search the [keywords field](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/using-keywords-in-microsoft-word-2010/c2c19349-609a-46a1-a11e-6049cd0084f6).

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Windows version 7 or newer, I suggest you learn how to use **Libraries**:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/libraries

They are very practical for what you want to do, and they are built in to Windows, you don't have to install any tool.

Comment: Microsoft removed this feature in Windows 8 and added it in Windows 8.1 again which is inactive by default. I don't wanna rely on Microsoft's odd decisions.

Comment: + this feature is only available in a specific location in drive C: