# Tag search for applications in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-search

The world has run out of unique names so apps often get fairly random ones. Joplin for notes, zint to generate QR codes, and so forth.

How can I tag these applications to make searching for them when I have forgotten the name easier?

In Windows Search from the start menu it does seem to have some kind of tagging system, e.g.

[image]

Edge has apparently been tagged with "browser". There doesn't seem to be a UI for this though. How can I tag any application so that I can search for it like this?

I am aware of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1179912/how-to-tag-applications), but I am not limiting the options to just Windows Search. I'm open to replacement search systems like Open-Start-Menu and Launchy, but as far as I can tell neither of those support tagging.

Comment: You can't.  You could seed the shortcut names with keywords as other people have suggested but I would simply suggest organizing your shortcuts in logical groups that make sense to you.  In exceptions looking through the complete list of programs list (All Apps) WIN11 Custom Start Menu Folders: https://i.imgur.com/CWArFxT.png

Comment: I'm surprised that one of the third party search systems doesn't support this. Maybe time to look at what would be needed to add it.